# Iterating through list items by name

Tags: list, development, splistitem, splist

I have a conditional statement that uses named columns of a list item.
Eg. Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3..
Is there a way that I can iterate through them to satisfy the problem I'm having when stating the column in the conditional statement?

```
if(oListItem["Stage 1"] == "Finished")
{}
if(oListItem["Stage 2"] == "Finished")
{}
//etc

//eg
int count = 0;
while(count<7)
{
   if(oListItem["Stage "+ count] == "Finished")
   {
        //do stuff..
        count++
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the above code, are you facing any issues in that? Seems like space in column name will be converted to `_x0020_` so you can access the column by internal name as `oListItem["Stage_x0020_"+ count]`

Comment: yes a little playing around with it and its working, thanks

Comment: I will post it as answer so you can tick mark to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like space in column name will be converted to `_x0020_` so you can access the column by internal name as `oListItem["Stage_x0020_"+ count]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the below code snippet for your requirement,here is what the code is going to do

- Get all fields and in each field it will check whether the column contains specific name here in this code snippet i am using "FieldTest" you can use your own
- It increments a variable each time and just checks if the field name contains the **incremented variable value** (in this case it is **count value**) then it loops through all Items and fetches each item value for the required Field

  ```
      ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);       
      List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("FieldTest");
      context.Load(context.Web);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      context.Load(list);
      context.Load(list.Fields);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      ListItemCollection itemcoll = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
      context.Load(itemcoll);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      int count = 0;
      foreach(Field field in list.Fields)
      {
          if(field.Title.Contains("Field"))
          {
              count++;
              bool status = field.Title.Contains(count.ToString());
              if(status==true)
              {
                  //Console.WriteLine("The Field Contains the integer" + " " + field.Title);
                  foreach(ListItem item in itemcoll)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Value of Item is" + " " + item[field.InternalName]);
                      Console.ReadLine();
                  }

              }
          }

      }
  ```